# VirtualHost issue on Debian 8

Tags: debian, apache-httpd

I got my own server on Debian 8.

My Website is on it (with a domain name). For the question my domain will be `domain.com`

My website is under `/var/www/website`
I got owncloud under `/var/www/owncloud`

My VirtualHost for `domain.com` point to `/var/www/website`, but if I do `domain.com/owncloud` in my browser, I get `owncloud` webpage. I don't know where my mistake is.

Here the `000-default.conf` virtual host :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        deny from all
        allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/owncloud>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        deny from all
        allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel info
</VirtualHost>
```

And here's my `domain.com.conf` VirtualHost :

```
<VirtualHost domain.com:80>

    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/website

    <Directory /var/www/website>
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log<br>
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined<br>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Like " ServerAlias IP_ADRESS/owncloud" just before "<Directory /var/www/owncloud>" ?

Comment: I go to /var/www/ and do `grep -rn owncloud /etc/apache2` and I still get the owncloud page when I go to domain.com/owncloud

Comment: `root@XXX:/var/www# grep -rn owncloud /etc/apache2
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:14:    <Directory /var/www/owncloud>`

Comment: I am being silly, of course. your default site works in every situation. To separate owncloud from domain.com you have to create another vhost/domain name, and not leave it as * as in Virtualhost: *

Comment: Could you post an answer with what do you mean ? I'm not pretty sure to understand ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration has the following line in it:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

The document root is the 'default' location where Apache will look for files. Since it points to `/var/www`, and since `/var/www/owncloud` exists, that means the webserver will look there if you enter `http://domain.com/owncloud` in your web browser.

Since you apparently don't want that, you should change the document root to something else. Newer Debian versions use `/var/www/html`, which could work. Alternatively, use the directory with the data for domain.com.